# Fitting Diagonal Divs to create a perfect X on page

Tags: html, css

I need a little help with fitting these diagonal divs to page to create a perfect X that I can then click on to bring either side of the X to the foreground through a js onclick to z-index change. I have all that covered but I've never dealt with diagonal div's and can't seem to make them fit to page properly to form a perfect X without getting a scroll bar:

```css
.x1 {
  background-color: #2cb5e8;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: skewY(-145deg);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 44%;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.x1>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(145eg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(145deg);
  transform: skewY(145deg);
}

.x2 {
  background-color: #0fb8ad;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: skewY(145deg);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 44%;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.x2>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(145deg);
  transform: skewY(145deg);
}

.page {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="x1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="x2">
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your requirement is completely unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure how it could get any more clear than:
help with fitting the diagonal divs to the page to create a perfect X without getting a scroll bar...
Did you even throw the code into an HTML file and try to view it or you decided to comment for no reason, much less read the post at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with javascript. You can simply get the distance of the box from the top of the container `.page` and add a padding-top to `.page` container itself.

Get the dimension of one of the bar example bar with class `.x1`

Compute the top position of `.x1` and padding the parent to shift down its contents

Snippet below

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("page")[0].style.paddingTop=-(document.getElementsByClassName("x1")[0].getBoundingClientRect().top)+"px";
```

```css
.x1 {
  background-color: #2cb5e8;
  /*opacity: 0.4;*/
  transform: skewY(-145deg);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 44%;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1002;
}

.x1>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(145eg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(145deg);
  transform: skewY(145deg);
}

.x2 {
  background-color: #0fb8ad;
  /*opacity: 0.4;*/
  transform: skewY(145deg);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 44%;
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 0%;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.x2>.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(145deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(145deg);
  transform: skewY(145deg);
}

.page {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="x1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="x2">
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works pretty well, but it is still causing a scroll bar, is there any way to scale all of that in a single page, without needing the scroll bar for whatever screen size? I'm familiar with css @media rules for adjusting min and max widths to scale elements for different screen sizes, but how would I go about scaling all this to fit the page without a scroll bar?